# Space time curvature due to electric charge or magnetic charges

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

since we know that gravitational force is nothing but a curvature in space-time.
I have a similar analogous for the electric or magnetic charges. Similarity is that both electromagnetic and gravitational forces follow the inverse square law. consequence of this can be that we can have a another interpretation of electron orbital motion causes by curvature in space due to electric charge (as mass of electron is very small so STR have no significance here). But problem is that we have two different type of charges (+ve and -ve) which gives repulsion and attraction, whereas in gravitation force mass always gives the attraction forces. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: We can view the electromagnetic field tensor as a curvature tensor just like the metric tensor of general relativity, and develop a very similar formalism, yes! Look at the section on gauge fields in this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory